# How to automatically remove punch holes from scanned documents?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, scanner

I have have so far scanned 50 thousand documents,  however all pages have punch holes in.  The holes are often in different places, so a basic crop won't work.

Does anyone have any ideas for automating the removal of the punch holes?

Comment: Software recommendation is off topic.

Comment: If they don't follow any common pattern you'll have a hard time. Either scanning them again or looking for a software that is suitable for the job is probably your best option.